# php array to comma separated string implode issues

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I'm having a problem in imploding an array to comma separated with double quotation.
My Script is as below:

```
<?php

$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

$string = rtrim(implode('", ', $arr), ',');

echo $string;
```

The output is:

`1", 2", 3", 4", 5", 6", 7", 8", 9`

But I want this output below:

`"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"`

So anyone can help me with this problem please?

Thanks!

Comment: I smell a bigger problem… where are you going to use this imploded string exactly?

Comment: `$string = '"' . implode('", "', $arr) . '"';`, this would solve it, but why would you need such output?

Comment: @deceze i am want to make a IPs output for a project that should be return like : '162.251.82.122', '162.251.82.250', '162.251.82.123', '162.251.82.251'

Comment: And why does your "project" need a string in this particular format? Can't you use proper *serialisation*, e.g. JSON?

Comment: @deceze Its a NET_DNS2 out put of A records of a host name and client want to display as i have provided.

Comment: Okay, fair enough, let's take that at face value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just throw this into the ring as alternative solution:

```
$string = trim(json_encode(array_map('strval', $arr)), '[]');
```

`json_encode` produces the desired result, just wrapped in a `[..]`; simply `trim` off the brackets.

Comment: (Because, who can resist a [bike-shed question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality), right?)

Comment: its not showing output as i am want check demo: http://ideone.com/oRHeFv

Comment: LOL, yup, it doesn't. ^_^;; You need to convert your values to strings… fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);    
$string = implode('", "', $arr);   
$string =  '"'.$string.'"';
echo $string;
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/Nq7oo)**

Answer (score -1):

You should have added the `Opening and Closing Closing Double Quotes` and No Need for the rtrim. The Following Code which you may test [Here](https://eval.in/636761) would do:

```
<?php

    $arr    = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    $string = '"' . implode('", "', $arr) .'"';

    echo $string;
```

Answer (score -2):

its work for you

```
 $arr    = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
 $string = '"'.implode('", "', $arr).'"';

echo $string;
```